# get categories the post was in and just been removed from

Tags: categories, hooks, save-post

I have a function hooked to the save_post hook. this function is mostly concerned with the categories that the post is in. 
My function does the following:

```
function post_save_hook($post_id){
    $categories = get_the_category($post_id);
    foreach($categories as $category){
        //Handle this category
    }
}
```

Say I have a category called `featured`, and a post was published under this category. then the same post was edited and removed from the `featured` category, in this case my function won't detect this change.

So what I want is to know if this post was in some category and removed from it.

Comment: _When_ do you need to know? Do you need a long term record, or do you just need to know when the category is removed?

Comment: No, I just need it this one time that the post was removed from this category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`save_post` runs too late](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3248) to do what you are trying to do. That hook fires after the post and related meta data are stored. The category has already been removed at that point, and WordPress keeps no record.

You will need to hook into the save process earlier, perhaps `pre_post_update`:

```
add_action(
  'pre_post_update',
  function($post_ID,$data) {
    var_dump($post_ID,$data);
    var_dump(get_the_category($post_ID));
    die;
  },
  10,2
);
```

Proof of concept code only, obviously.